# how to stop updates like "Language support" and "Handheld device font ..." on PC

Tags: updates

My desktop PCs use English only and are NOT handheld devices ever. So how do I stop getting updates for "Language selector for Ubuntu" and "Handheld device font with extensive style and language support" ?

It is becoming annoying having to do so many updates and wasting so much bandwidth on stuff I will never want.

Is there a distro that contains a functioning desktop and Ubuntu Software Centre and nothing else? Maybe an installation menu that you can tick the things you need, rather than the "here's everything you could possibly ever need" approach.

Comment: This is both the major advantage of Ubuntu and a major disadvantage. In general, Ubuntu makes it "easy" by including relatively more dependencies (rather then less). The language packs are notorious for this. You can try a minimal install of Ubuntu and install only the packages you feel you need, however, you will likely have the same problem. Your best option is likely to put those packages on hold, meaning they will not be updated. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package

Comment: Thanks for that. The link suggests I don't want to hold, as the last thing I want is to have to start sorting holds out if any dependencies do need updating. So "easy" means "get them all". Ho-hum.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go; http://scarygliders.net/2012/04/01/quicktips-stop-apt-downloading-translations-indexes/

1) Edit (or create) a file called /etc/apt/apt.conf
    sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf
Then add the following directive;
    Acquire {
               Languages "none";
    };

2) Remove any existing “*i18n*” files from /var/lib/apt/lists/
    cd /var/lib/apt/lists

Now, you have a choice; one or the other of the following;

A) The safer method;
    sudo rm -i *i18n*
The system will ask for confirmation for each file you wish to delete – there may be quite a lot of these :)

B) The time-saving but be careful how you type this one method;
    sudo rm *i18n*

Now if you perform an apt-get update, or update via aptitude or synaptic, your system should no longer try do download the Translation Indexes.

This works for me on Debian and Ubuntu.